# Use the path a user enters in the URL in the page

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular6

I'm building an app in angular 6 and i'm looking for a functionality with which i can use whatever the user is typing in the Browser's address bar in the site,

For example:

User enters domain "`myproject.example/5/cool`"

then the website should give output "User `5` is soo `cool`!"

Is there a way to read what the user types in the URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: user types the url in the any input box or in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: I want it to work when the user enters it in the address bar of the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to read the url in the address bar. There's two way to do it : with the `ActivatedRoute` and with `Router`.

## ActivatedRoute

`ActivatedRoute` will require a `app-routing.module.ts` with the elements you want to display in your component:

```
{ path: ':customerId/:state', component: YourComponent }
```

And, in your component :

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        this.customerId = params.get('customerId');
        this.state = params.get('state');
    });
  }
```

You'll only need to construct your output with `customerId` and `state`.

## Router

If you don't want to use the routing (or you can't for whatever reason), you can also use `Router` to read the url. You'll juste need to parse it :

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {
      this.href = this.router.url;
 }
```